# UIView not filling its frame

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, ios6

I'm trying to use [this XYPieChart](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart) here, the demo works great and it looks beautiful. Problem is, whenever I try to recreate it on a Storyboard, the chart appears incredibly small and I can't seem to resize it. I've played around with all the settings and set the frame of the property and nothing seems to work. I've tried resizing it to the entire screen with:

```
[self.pieChart setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

Still the same result except the frame stretches across the screen and everything is grey. Anyone, this is how it's coming out, the grey is the frame and the XYPieChart loads in the center:

[image]

I'm still fairly new and I've been searching how to remedy this but I can't formulate a good enough search query that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried setting the pieRadius property? This should increase the size of the pie chart.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm a moron. After all this... that was it. This is what I was hoping would happen, that I was looking so hard in the wrong spot. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks buddy, you're the man.

Comment: As to _why_, it's probably because you're using a storyboard with autolayout in place - here, where initWithCoder is called on the object, it will have a frame size of 0, which is not dealt with in the code, and there is no support for resizing / redrawing everything when the view's frame is changed.

Comment: will the actual pie pieces work with auto layout? i've placed a view on my xib, connected it to XYPieChart class and setup the layout constraints. i have a label in the middle of the pie view as a subview like in the sample demo. the label is properly centered but not the pie. it's not sizing itself based on the size of the piechart view.

Comment: yeah so my view that i've set to be the XYPieChart is being centered nicely (since i colored it red) but the pie is actually not inside of that view space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set the pieRadius property on the chart.

If you change this it should make the pie bigger.

Comment: how do i center one of these xyPieCharts in its parent view? I have view that connects to the XYPieChart class inside a UICollectionCell. I setup the auto layout constraints for the view in IB but it looks like the actual pie image doesn't take that into account. I'm also trying to setPieCenter with value from CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width /2.0, [self bounds].size.width / 2.0) but pie is always off center, bottom right of my cell....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to AutoLayout. If you want to keep using AutoLayout in your project, you can simply change your viewDidAppear this way:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.pieChart.pieRadius = MIN(self.pieChart.frame.size.width/2, self.pieChart.frame.size.height/2) - 10;
    self.pieChart.self.pieCenter = CGPointMake(self.pieChart.frame.size.width/2, self.pieChart.frame.size.height/2);
    self.pieChart.labelRadius = self.pieChart.pieRadius/2;
    self.pieChart.labelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:MAX((int)self.pieChart.pieRadius/10, 5)];


    [self.pieChart reloadData];

}
```

At the moment viewDidAppear will be called, your pieChart frame will be already updated with sizes provided by AutoLayout.

Comment: I can't understand why answer is downvoted: problem is really related to autolayout so that with my code you don't have to set manually the radius but you can desume it directly from the view you lay out on the storyboard (the code i provided is taken from XYPieChart class)